# How close is the exponential of a near-idempotent to $1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $p$ be an element of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$. One can show that if $p^2=p$, then $e^{2\pi i p}=1$.

**Question 1:** What is the largest $\delta>0$ (independent of $A$) such that whenever

$$\|p^2-p\|<\delta,$$

we have $\|e^{2\pi ip}-1\|<1$?

It's possible that that answer to Question 1 depends on $\|p\|$ and/or $\|1-p\|$. If so let's say that both of these quantities are less than some constant $C$. Then the relevant question would be:

**Question 2:** What is the largest $\delta_C>0$ (independent of $A$) such that whenever

$$\|p^2-p\|<\delta_C,$$

we have $\|e^{2\pi ip}-1\|<1$?

*Remark:* Using the holomorphic functional calculus, one can construct an idempotent $e$ somewhat close to $p$, but with possibly larger norm. One can show using this and the fact that
$$\|e^a-e^b\|\leq e^{\|a-b\|}\|a-b\|,$$
that if $\|p\|$ and $\|1-p\|$ are small enough, then $\delta$ can be taken to be $\frac{1}{4}$. But this number seems a bit mysterious to me. I feel like there might be something simpler I am missing, or perhaps something like this is known in the literature?

Comment: I assume you want the largest $\delta$? Since $\delta=0$ works, there cannot be "smallest".

Comment: Yes indeed...thanks!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to assume that $p$ is self adjoint, or at least that $\|p-p^*\|<\delta$?

Comment: @Aweygan Initially I was thinking about the case without this assumption, but that would also be interesting.